# jQuery Promise - fire up done even if some json did not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm using promise but sometimes I can't get JSON from various reason in one case, how can I fire up done even if some of JSON is missing, with this code at the moment I'm having only failed message

```
$.when(
    arrayResults[0] ? $.getJSON("url") : null,
    arrayResults[1] ? $.getJSON("url") : null,
    arrayResults[2] ? $.getJSON("url") : null

).done(function () { }).fail(function () {
    console.log('Failed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `deferred.always(cb)`:

```
$.when(
    arrayResults[0] ? $.getJSON("url") : null,
    arrayResults[1] ? $.getJSON("url") : null,
    arrayResults[2] ? $.getJSON("url") : null
)
.done(function () { console.log('I will run when the promise was resolved') })
.fail(function () { console.log('I will run when the promise was rejected') })
.always(function() { console.log('I will always fire, regardless of previous results') })
```

See further information here: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery v3+ it is [Promises A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) compliant so you can add  `catch()` to the request promise

Whenever you *return* from within a catch it resolves the prior promise and passes whatever you return to the next `then()` in the promise chain

```js
function getData(url){
  return $.getJSON(url)
     .then(data=>data)
     .catch(resolveFailure)

}

function resolveFailure(jqXhr) { 
  // return whatever you want here. I added the status in case that is of interest
  // could return `false` or string or whatever
  // can also log any issues back to server if needed
  return {
    error: true,
    status: jqXhr.status,
    statusText: jqXhr.statusText
  };
}


var req = getData('https://api.myjson.com/bins/l9ywp'),
    req2 = getData('https://httpbin.org/FAIL'),
    req3 = getData('https://api.myjson.com/bins/l9ywp');

// could also replace `$.when with `Promise.all()`
$.when(req, req2, req3).then(function(r1, r2, r3) {
  // validate the arguments based on whatever you return in the catch()
  console.log('r1', r1);
  console.log('r2', r2);// object returned from catch()
  console.log('r3', r3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Im having problem in function then between 'data' and => i got error expression expected and after ' ) ' expecting new line or semicolon

Comment: Also with this code I still cant fire up when. forms just not loading. it always failing at : last req4 = getData(Url);

Comment: change `.then(data=>data)` to `.then(function(data){ return data})`. The first is ES6 syntax

Comment: Sorry if im too overworking you now, but im exhausted and ma brain barely work, now your example look nice but while doing this im getting "Uncaught TypeError: $.getJSON(...).then(...).catch is not a function"

Comment: What version of jQuery? It's probably not v3

Comment: just checked and its 2.1.1 ;/ problem is we cant change this